# (Temp) Storage of JSON Search Results in Web App

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, html, sessionstorage

I'm working on a search function for my Web app (HTML, JS & CSS only). I'm using jQuery's .getjson() method to retrieve data from a feed and display those results on a page. Inside of an .each() statement I'm adding HTML markup to the results making some of the elements links to outside sources.

The issue is when a visitor initiates a search on my Web app and clicks on a link from the results to an outside page, then uses the Back button on the browser to go back to the results page, all of the search results are cleared and another search needs to be initiated.

I'd like to temporarily save the search results so if a user clicks on a link from the results, then presses the Back button to come back to the app, all of the results will be available without the new for another search.

Taking this one step further, it would also be cool is the results for past searchs also persists so if the visitor continues to press the Back button, they can see all of their previous searches (with a given limit of course).

HTML5 sessionStorage seems to be ideal for this, but the information that I found points to a tedious coding solution. Can't I just save all of the json results as a JS object and have them re-rendered by my each statement when the visitor presses the Back button? I'm definitely open to using a code library or plugin for this problem.

Comment: what if between the moment user left the page and clicks the back button, the actual results had changed? to me it sounds that a new search would be a better solution, as long as the user will not need to type anything again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://brian.io/lawnchair/ is a good little library for API for persistence. You can use the same syntax as an abstraction for different storage options http://brian.io/lawnchair/adapters/

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to approach this issue, one is caching the results on your server and populating the view on-demand, and number two is like you previously mentioned - use sessionStorage. sessionStorage (IMO) has a very straightforward API. You can either use sessionStorage.setItem(key, value) or sessionStorage.getItem(key) -- other methods are available as well such as sessionStorage.key(index), sessionStorage.removeItem(key) and sessionStorage.clear(). It would probably be useful to include a cross-browser polyfill solution for sessionStorage, you can check out the "Web Storage" polyfills section at Modernizr: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills -- Have fun :-/

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

Every time the user searches, change the hash in the url to a unique string (e.g. 'search-{userInput}' ... you could of course just forget about the 'search-', but I like my urls in pretty). This should give you back-button support. Then:

Alternative A:
Listen for the hashChange Event, parse the window.location.hash and resend the request to your search URL. Theoretically, unless adding the timestamp to the URL or crazy stuff like that, the caching mechanism of your browser should kick in here. If not, it means an additional request, but that should be ok, shouldn't it?

Alternative B:
Extend your existing search query mechanism by caching the results to localStorage (just don't forget to JSON.stringify it beforehand and use a something-{timestamp} key). Then listen for the hashChange Event and pull the results from your localStorage. Personally, I wouldn't recommend this solution as you're clogging up the localStorage (afaik there's a limit at 2.5mB for some browsers).

You're probably going to have to find ways to circumvent missing browser support for at least the hashChange Event, JSON stringify/parse and LocalStorage, but I'm optimistic that there are enough libs/plugins out there by now.

Answer (score 0):

You think too complicated: your search form most likely does not change the url! Use GET instead of POST and you have the desired result. Right now the browser has no way of knowing which state of the website you want to show and by default shows the first - the empty search form

Caching could be added as suggested, but that really is not the problem here

Comment: I like the sound of what your saying, but I'm not sure that I completely understand. I'm getting the data via jQuery's getjson method and adding it to the page with jQuery (appendTo specifically). How would I implement your solution in this situation?

Comment: so you are using AJAX instead of forms... ok. well, then my answer isn't really correct as it assumed forms. But the principle remains the same: update the URL to be able to use the browser's history! for AJAX and jQuery there actually quite a few history plugins but in the end it comes done to changing the hashtag of your website (if you dont already use hashs then this is easier). if the user searches for, say, "banana" then you update the URL with e.g.  `window.location.hash = "q=banana"` - though `window.location.hash = "banana"` would suffice